# Netbeans 12.4 C/C++

Tags: java, c++, c, netbeans

I need to build C/C++ projects on Netbeans 12.4 with Ubuntu 18.04. There have been a long list of failures - trying earlier versions of Netbeans and even Eclipse. I can't find a simple tutorial / example for using the Lightweight C/C++.

Here is what I have done so far:

1. Install Netbeans 12.4 with `sudo apt install netbeans`. This loaded java 11 jdk.
2. Wrote and tested the usual Java Hello World.
3. Installed build essentials with `sudo apt install build-essential`
4. checked that gcc, make, and gdb are accessible.
5. tried to start a C/C++ project as follows:

   1. New Project -> C/C++ / Lightweight C/C++ Project
   2. Next-> project path set to /home/david/NetBeansProjects
   3. Next-> Compile Commands: ... and I'm stuck. It seems to want the tool set to use, but I can't find it.

Any pointers appreciated.

Comment: How did you get Netbeans 12.4 installed on 18.04 LTS? Its repositories provide only [version 10](https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/netbeans).

Comment: I installed Netbeans 12.4 with one line: sudo apt install netbeans. This was a massive install including java 11 jdk, but resulting in the presence of this apparently unusable Lightweight C/C++.

Comment: Today, the same commands are giving me Netbeans 10.0. This thing is out of control (sigh!). If you try to run a Java test program, it has a bunch of untracceable errors.

Answer (score 2):

To get full C/C++ support in NetBeans you have to enable plugin which was shipped with 8.x NetBeans family by doing the following:

1. Launch NetBeans
2. Go to *Tools* → *Plugins*
3. Open *Settings* tab and check set *NetBeans 8.2 Plugin Portal* as *Active*
4. Switch to *Available plugins* tab, click on *Check for Newest* and select *C/C++* for installation by right mouse click on it

   [image: C/C++ selected to install using 8.2 plugin portal]
5. Wait for plugins installation and restart NetBeans
6. Launch NetBeans again, go to *File* → *New project*, choose C/C++ and then you will see the following:

   [image: new C/C++ project]
7. Compile and enjoy.

Note: I have tested above method using NetBeans 12.4 (installed using Ubuntu Make by `umake ide netbeans`).

Useful tutorial from NetBeans: [C/C++ Projects Quick Start Tutorial](https://netbeans.apache.org/kb/docs/cnd/quickstart.html) .

Comment: Not sure I'd call it useful, since it omits the tremendously helpful info about installing the plugin.

Comment: Thank you so much for your post, I didn't know I needed to enable the Netbeans 8.2 Plugin Portal.